# How to load an object into memory for entire django project to see?

Tags: python, django

I'd assume it would just be loaded into settings.py, and then the object would just be imported from the settings, but I just wanted to know if there was a more standard or recommended way to do this. Where do people usually load their items that their entire project needs see?

Ex.

```
# settings.py
...
something_large = json.loads(...)


# whatever models.py, views.py, etc
from Project.settings import something_large  #Is this the proper way to do it?
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could load it in, say, a `data` module in your app to make it cleaner.

(I'm also showing how to load a file from the same directory a module is in.)

```
project/
   settings.py
   ...
myapp/
   __init__.py
   data.py
   huge_static_data.json
   models.py
   ...
```

`myapp/data.py`:

```
with file(os.path.join(os.dirname(__file__), "huge_static_data.json")) as in_f:
  something_large = json.load(in_f)
```

`myapp/models.py`:

```
from myapp.data import something_large
```

Python's import system ensures the data will just be loaded once, when the module is first imported.

Comment: I like this answer, but only if the data belongs to the app. Or else, I think it would make more sense just to load it into the main project.

Comment: Of course. If multiple apps in the project need the same data, it may be may be a good idea to have a "common app" to put this in, instead of "polluting" the project directory.